# jquery ajax not working when contentType is set

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I have two node js servers running on localhost:3000 and localhost:3001. When I make an ajax POST request from localhost:3001 to localhost:3000, nothing happens. I've checked the logs on localhost:3000 and it is not even receiving the POST request.

This is the code where I'm making the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"http://localhost:3000/post/",
    contentType:"application/json",
    dataType:'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({name:'Bruce Wayne'}),
    success:function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

However, when I remove the contentType field or change it to "text/plain" instead of "application/json", it works. On localhost:3000 I'm sending these headers too in the response.

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
```

I've gone through a lot of questions on SO already and tried everything. Can someone help me figure out what the problem is here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a long running issue with jQuery, personally, don't ask me why, but the working solution is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:  "http://localhost:3000/post/",
    // contentType: "application/json", // Remove this bit.
    // dataType: 'json',                // Remove this bit.
    data: JSON.stringify({name:'Bruce Wayne'}),
    success:function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

And don't give `application/json` or `javascript/json` or `text/json` while you are sending the response headers. Let it be either: `text/html` or `text/plain`. Let me know if it works.

Comment: What you said is true and it does work when I comment out the contentType. But then I'm not able to parse the request on the server side as it's not in the right format. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: @HarshaReaper How are you trying to parse this? That's the reason I said I am not sure why this is happening and moreover, this works. `:P`

Comment: I'm using express.js and trying to parse through bodyParser.json().

Comment: @HarshaReaper I am not so good in NodeJS. Well, what is the problem are you getting? Can't you parse it using `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: Yup. I'm receiving the request body as {'{"Name": "Bruce Wayne"}': ''}. Basically, the string which we need to parse is being sent as the key in an object with an empty value. This is making things very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by myself and just going to post this answer in case someone using express and node runs into a similar problem in the future.

Instead of adding those three headers to the response in my controller function like

```
router.get('/post', function(req, res){
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    ... //rest of the code
})
```

I created a middleware and used it in the main app.js file and it's magically working. I have absolutely no idea why, but it works.

```
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
next();
};

app.use(allowCrossDomain);
```

Comment: LoL... That's funny... `:)`